# Where has the “followers” button gone?

Tags: facebook-timeline

I cannot find the people who are following me on Facebook.

[image]

I've tried searching it on the *About* page, but I didn't find it. And I also tried in the friend's selection, but it was not there. So what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

The Followers tab requires that you have Followers enabled (set to "Everybody") to begin with. That is located in the **Follower Settings** section of your **Account Settings**

[image]

Once you enable followers, the tab is located on your profile in the **Friends** section. There is a tab for **Followers**.

[image: followers tab]

Comment: ummmm see the pic i posted..... the follower's button is not on the friend's section .-.

Comment: Did you make sure you have followers enabled?

Comment: I just confirmed that if I change my "Who Can Follow Me" setting (see the second screenshot) to "Friends Only", the "Followers" tab disappears. I change the setting back to "Everybody" and the tab reappears.

Comment: edited the answer to swap the positions of the screenshots.